# How to add multiple ActionListeners for multiple buttons in one GUI in Java Swing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, actionlistener

I am working with Jadex for my simulation, which is Java based. I am working on massage broadcasting among different agents.
I have a GUI with two buttons, one is the send button and the other one is the check button. 
It works fine and when I press the send button it sends the message to other agents. My problem is I want also send the result of the check button to other agents. 
Appreciate your help.
My GUI Code for this agent.

```
public class TranslationGuiBDI extends BobGuiBDI
{
    public TranslationGuiBDI(final IExternalAccess agent)
    {
        super(agent);
        JButton Checkes = new JButton("Checkes");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();//new BorderLayout());
        p.add(Checkes);//, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        Checkes.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                agent.scheduleStep(new IComponentStep<Void>()
                {
                    public IFuture<Void> execute(IInternalAccess ia)
                    {
                        IFuture<Collection<ITranslationService>>    transser    = ia.getComponentFeature(IRequiredServicesFeature.class).getRequiredServices("transser");
                        transser.addResultListener(new DefaultResultListener<Collection<ITranslationService>>()
                        {
                            public void resultAvailable(Collection<ITranslationService> result)
                            {
                                for(Iterator<ITranslationService> it=result.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
                                {
                                    ITranslationService cs = it.next();
                                    cs.getUserProfile().addResultListener(new DefaultResultListener<UserProfile>()
                                    {
                                        public void resultAvailable(UserProfile result)
                                        {
                                            addMessage(result.toString());
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        return IFuture.DONE;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

And Bob's GUI :

```
public class BobGuiBDI extends JFrame {

    /** The textfield with received messages. */
    protected JTextArea received;

    /** The agent owning the gui. */
    protected IExternalAccess agent;

    //-------- constructors --------

    /**
     *  Create the user interface
     */
    public BobGuiBDI(IExternalAccess agent)
    {
        super(agent.getComponentIdentifier().getName());
        this.agent  = agent;
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        received = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        final JTextField message = new JTextField();
        JButton send = new JButton("send");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(message, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(send, BorderLayout.EAST);

        getContentPane().add(received, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        send.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                final String text = message.getText(); 
                BobGuiBDI.this.agent.scheduleStep(new IComponentStep<Void>()
                {
                    public IFuture<Void> execute(IInternalAccess ia)
                    {
                        IIntermediateFuture<IlogSevice> fut = ia.getComponentFeature(IRequiredServicesFeature.class).getRequiredServices("chatservices");
                        fut.addResultListener(new IIntermediateResultListener<IlogSevice>()
                        {
                            public void resultAvailable(Collection<IlogSevice> result)
                            {
                                for(Iterator<IlogSevice> it=result.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
                                {
                                    IlogSevice cs = it.next();
                                    try
                                    {
                                        cs.message(BobGuiBDI.this.agent.getComponentIdentifier().getName(), text,text);
                                    }
                                    catch(Exception e)
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("Could not send message to: "+cs);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            public void intermediateResultAvailable(IlogSevice cs)
                            {
                                System.out.println("found: "+cs);
                                cs.message(BobGuiBDI.this.agent.getComponentIdentifier().getName(), text,text);
                            }

                            public void finished()
                            {
                            }

                            public void exceptionOccurred(Exception exception)
                            {
                            }

                        });
                        return IFuture.DONE;
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e)
            {
                BobGuiBDI.this.agent.killComponent();
                BobGuiBDI.this.agent    = null;
            }
        });

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     *  Method to add a new text message.
     *  @param text The text.
     */
    public void addMessage(final String text)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                received.append(text+"\n");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 3) Is your question *"How to X?"*?  If so, add it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37004630/edit).  If not, think of a specific question and do the same (edit).

Comment: @AndrewThompson 2,3 already addressed. Thanks

Comment: `It works fine and when I press the send button it sends the message to other agents. My problem is I want also send the result of the check button to other agents.` - well I don't understand the problem. If it already works for one button, then copy the code from that button. Or better yet make it a method that can be invoked for both buttons. Then you just pass a parameter to the method indicating the message you want to send.

Comment: @camickr The translation Gui is the extension of the Bob Gui. Is that work in this case?

Comment: The translation GUI has access to all the methods of the bob GUI.

Comment: @camickr I tried what you said. Copy the code for the other button but it did not work. I invoked the message but no success.

Comment: Well, you have a bug in your code. We are not mind readers. We can't guess what you are doing. You have already been asked to post an `MCVE` or a `SSCE` (see the first comment). You haven't so we can't help.